# React Native App Stuck on Splash Screen during Build, Works Fine with 'npx expo start'

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo

I'm encountering a frustrating issue in my React Native project, where the app gets stuck on the splash screen during the build process. To provide more details, this problem only arises when I build the app using the typical build process, while running npx expo start or npx expo start --no-dev --minify works perfectly fine.

Additionally, I've attempted to investigate the issue by installing and searching for logs using adb, but I haven't been able to find any clues there. This issue has been persistent for several days, and I'd greatly appreciate any insights or solutions from the community.

*Nevegation.jsx*

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import Main from './Main';
import CustomDrawer from './CustomDrawer';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Explorar from './Explorar';
import DetallNoticia from './DetallNoticia';
import Notificacions from './config/Notificacions';
import Configurar from './Configurar';
import { Share } from 'react-native';
import categories from '../data/categories';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';


const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();



function NavegationDrawerApp() {

  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}
      screenOptions={{
        drawerActiveBackgroundColor: '#eb4947',
        drawerActiveTintColor: '#fff',
        drawerInactiveTintColor: '#000',
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        drawerLabelStyle: {
          marginLeft: -10,
          fontSize: 15,
        },

        headerTitle: () => (
          <Image source={require('../../assets/img/logo.jpg')} style={{ width: 200, height: 50, resizeMode: 'contain', borderRadius: 10, }} />
        ),
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',

        headerBackground: () => (
          <Image
            style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%', height: '100%', resizeMode: 'cover' }}
            source={require('../../assets/img/REDBG.jpg')}
          />
        ),

      }

      }
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Portada" component={Main} options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <Ionicons name="trending-up" size={22} color={color} />
        ),
        menu: true
      }
      } />

      <Drawer.Screen name="Societat" component={Explorar} options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <Ionicons name="people-outline" size={22} color={color} />

        ),
      }
      }
      />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Política" component={Explorar} options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <Ionicons name="megaphone-outline" size={22} color={color} />
        ),
      }
      } />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Economia" component={Explorar} options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <Ionicons name="wallet-outline" size={22} color={color} />
        ),
      }
      } />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Cultura" component={Explorar} options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <Ionicons name="ribbon-outline" size={22} color={color} />
        ),
      }
      } />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Vins i caves" component={Explorar} options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <Ionicons name="wine-outline" size={22} color={color} />
        ),
      }
      } />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Mon Casteller" component={Explorar} options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <Ionicons name="body-outline" size={22} color={color} />
        ),
      }
      } />

      <Drawer.Screen name="Esports" component={Explorar} options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <Ionicons name="football-outline" size={22} color={color} />
        ),
      }
      } />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Entrevistes" component={Explorar} options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <Ionicons name="book-outline" size={22} color={color} />
        ),
      }
      } />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Salut" component={Explorar} options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
          <Ionicons name="medkit-outline" size={22} color={color} />
        ),
      }
      } />


    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}


const MainNavigation = ({ notiTouched }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (notiTouched) {
      navigation.navigate('DetallNoticia', { noticia: notiTouched });
    }


  }, [notiTouched])



  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: true,
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerTitleStyle: { fontSize: 18, fontWeight: "bold" },
        headerStyle: {
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
          borderBottomColor: "black",
        },
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="-"
        component={NavegationDrawerApp}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="DetallNoticia"
        component={DetallNoticia}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          headerShown: true, title: "", headerStyle: { borderBottomWidth: 0, },
          headerRight: () => (<TouchableOpacity style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
            onPress={() => {

              fetch('https://cargol.outlius.com/noticies/' + route.params.noticia)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                  //busca el nom de la categoria a partir de data[0].category
                  let catName = categories.find(category => category.ID == data[0].category)?.nom.toLowerCase();

                 // let catName = categories.find(category => category.ID == route.params.noticia)?.nom.toLowerCase();
                  catName = catName.replace(/ /g, "-");
                  
                  let urlShare = "https://elcargol.com/" + catName + "/" + data[0].id + "-" + data[0].alias;


                  Share.share({
                    message: data[0].titol + "\n" + urlShare
                  });
                })

            }} >

            <Ionicons name="share-social-outline" size={22} color="black" />
          </TouchableOpacity>),
        })}


      />
      <Stack.Screen name="Notificacions" component={Notificacions}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            borderBottomWidth: 0,
          },
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="Configurar" component={Configurar}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            borderBottomWidth: 0,
          },
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};



export default MainNavigation;
```

*Package.json*

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "expo": "^49.0.0",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-progress-steps": "^1.3.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `useLegacyImplementation`, I think there is an issue with react-native-reanimated.

```
function NavegationDrawerApp() {

return (
  <Drawer.Navigator useLegacyImplementation={true} drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}
    screenOptions={{
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, the solution you provided didn't resolve the issue. The problem of the app getting stuck on the splash screen during the build process persists.

If you have any other suggestions or ideas to troubleshoot this issue, I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you once again for your assistance.